# Suitable framework for core java developers?

Tags: java, frameworks

I have a experience in core - java and have been working more than 4 years in core - java only. and i have been using framework that has been developed by my own organization. But now i got bored using it repeatedly. Planned to switch any another framework that suitable to develop the core java application? 
P.S : I have 0% knowledge about any frameworks that has been playing the java around the world?

Comment: I think Spring is the best framework for development that there is.

Comment: Framework to do *what*???

Comment: Thanks Dave fro making me clear, Have edited my question what exactly expected to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be Spring Framework: http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Apart from normal spring applications which can use Dependency-Injection and AOP, you can use it as an MVC architecture. ROO, which is a rapid development tool from Spring supports easy and fast development(http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/). Core support for dependency injection, transaction management, web applications, data access, messaging, testing and more.

You can use it in conjunction with Hibernate: http://hibernate.org/

They have ORM, search, validator etc. Hibernate is well known for its excellent stability and quality, proven by the acceptance and use by tens of thousands of Java developers :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Hibernate framework is a better ORM for database access than jdbc. It's also database independent.